# Multiple belongs_to in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am looking to model a messaging system.

At the moment I have two models, User and Message. I wish for there to be multiple associations on a message to a user, the sender and receiver.

This is my active record migration for my Message.

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.string :body
      t.belongs_to :sender, :class_name=>'User', :foreign_key=>'sent_from'
      t.belongs_to :recipient, :class_name=>'User', :foreign_key=>'sent_to'

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

However when I attempt to create a new Message I get the following error:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    Message.create(body: "Hello World", 1, 2)
  end
end
```

However I get the following error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.recipients: INSERT INTO "messages" ("body", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)):
```

What am I missing here? What is the best way to model this relationship?

Comment: Did you add the foreign_key options to the belongs_to association in the model too? i.e. `class Message; belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'sent_from'; end`

Answer (score 0):

A few things wrong here.

According to the [docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference), `belongs_to` (which is an alias for `references`) in a migration takes the options: `:type`, `:index`, `:foreign_key`, `:polymorphic`, and `:null`. There is no `:class_name`, and `:foreign_key` should be `true` or `false` (defaults to `false`).

So, your migration should probably look more like:

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.string :body
      t.belongs_to :sender
      t.belongs_to :recipient

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

`message.rb` will look something like:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender,    class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User'

  ...
end
```

I don't know why you're creating a `Message` in the `index` action of your `DashboardController`. But, hey, whatever floats your boat.

But, it should probably look more like:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    Message.create(body: "Hello World", sender_id: 1, recipient_id: 2)
  end

end
```

Or, it might look something like:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    sender = User.find_by(...)
    recipient = User.find_by(...)
    Message.create(body: "Hello World", sender: sender, recipient: recipient)
  end

end
```

Rails can be pretty smart, but when you do:

```
Message.create(body: "Hello World", 1, 2)
```

it's not so smart to know whether 1 is a sender or a recipient. Same with 2. You need to tell rais which is which.